# Dangers of using CTR mode for encryption

Tags: ctr, file-encryption

I know that it is never suggested to use the same key or key/IV pair twice for a stream cipher or for a block cipher operating in CTR mode. Filesystem-level encryption reuses the same key for a file when it is edited.

Would it be an okay idea or a bad idea to use CTR mode for such encryption? Would it require changing the IV upon each edit and re-encrypting to make sure it is secure?

Comment: So, I wouldn't say that "it is never suggested" but rather that "it is catastrophic."

Answer (score 3):

From your question I'll assume that you do not plan to use strong means of authentication along with CTR encryption. If you do, the first point is invalid.

- **Never ever use CTR mode alone.** If you use CTR mode alone (i.e. without authentication) you allow attackers *bit level* precision for changing files. This can result in very undesirable decryptions where important data was changed because the attacker knew the format, the position and the previous content.
- **Never ever re-use a nonce + key pair**. If you do re-use a {nonce, counter} and key pair, you allow an attacker to perform a *ciphertext only attack* (the worst sort of attack imaginable) and the complete security of the system should break down. Note further that re-using the same counter at any space-time combination suffices.

Comment: Furthermore, cipher modes like XTS are practically purpose-built for filesystem encryption.